# Flink taskmanager stucks (100% cpu usage) after failing to make a checkpoint/savepoint

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis

-- Solved problem by changing state backend from filesystem to rocksdb --

Running Flink 1.9 atop on AWS EMR.
Flink app uses kinesis stream as input data and another kinesis stream as output.
Recently the checkpoint size has grown to 1 gigabyte (due to more data).
Sometimes, during an attempt to take a checkpoint - the application begins to utilize the entire processor resource (occurs several times a day)

Metrics:

[LA (emr ec2 core node with job/task managers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1STU.png)

[Run Loop Time - kinesis consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2obx.png)

[Records Per Fetch - kinesis consumer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HVtz.png)

[Task manager GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVvlJ.png)

jobmanager logs

```
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:55:27,399","thread":"Checkpoint Timer","file":"CheckpointCoordinator.java","line":"617","message":"Triggering checkpoint 1232 @ 1598331327244 for job 0039825bafae26bc34db88e037a1dae3."}

{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:24,509","thread":"flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7010","file":"ResourceManager.java","line":"1144","message":"The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_1597960565773_0003_01_000002 timed out."}

{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:24,510","thread":"flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7010","file":"ResourceManager.java","line":"805","message":"Closing TaskExecutor connection container_1597960565773_0003_01_000002 because: The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_1597960565773_0003_01_000002  timed out."}
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:24,514","thread":"flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7015","file":"Execution.java","line":"1493","message":"Sink: kinesis-events-sink (1/1) (573401e241fe0a0ac0a8a54c81c4eefd) switched from RUNNING to FAILED."}
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_1597960565773_0003_01_000002  timed out.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(ResourceManager.java:1146)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatMonitorImpl.run(HeartbeatMonitorImpl.java:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:397)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:24,515","thread":"flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7015","file":"ExecutionGraph.java","line":"1324","message":"Job JOB_NAME_HIDDEN (0039825bafae26bc34db88e037a1dae3) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING."}
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The heartbeat of TaskManager with id container_1597960565773_0003_01_000002  timed out.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$TaskManagerHeartbeatListener.notifyHeartbeatTimeout(ResourceManager.java:1146)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.heartbeat.HeartbeatMonitorImpl.run(HeartbeatMonitorImpl.java:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:397)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:190)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:74)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:152)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

task managers logs

```
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:17,504","thread":"kpl-daemon-0003","file":"LogInputStreamReader.java","line":"59","message":"[2020-08-25 04:58:02.469832] [0x00007394][0x00007f2673d70700] [info] [processing_statistics_logger.cc:127] (sensing-events-test) Aver
age Processing Time: -nan ms"}
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:17,504","thread":"kpl-daemon-0003","file":"LogInputStreamReader.java","line":"59","message":"[2020-08-25 04:58:17.469922] [0x00007394][0x00007f2673d70700] [info] [processing_statistics_logger.cc:109] Stage 1 Triggers: { stream
: 'sensing-events-test', manual: 0, count: 0, size: 0, matches: 0, timed: 0, UserRecords: 0, KinesisRecords: 0 }"}
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:17,504","thread":"kpl-daemon-0003","file":"LogInputStreamReader.java","line":"59","message":"[2020-08-25 04:58:17.469977] [0x00007394][0x00007f2673d70700] [info] [processing_statistics_logger.cc:112] Stage 2 Triggers: { stream
: 'sensing-events-test', manual: 0, count: 0, size: 0, matches: 0, timed: 0, KinesisRecords: 0, PutRecords: 0 }"}
{"level":"INFO","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:17,504","thread":"kpl-daemon-0003","file":"LogInputStreamReader.java","line":"59","message":"[2020-08-25 04:58:17.469992] [0x00007394][0x00007f2673d70700] [info] [processing_statistics_logger.cc:127] (sensing-events-test) Aver
age Processing Time: -nan ms"}
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2020-08-25 04:58:28,535","thread":"flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-628","file":"FatalExitExceptionHandler.java","line":"40","message":"FATAL: Thread 'flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-628' produced an uncaught exception. Stopping the pr
ocess..."}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.reflect.UTF8.encode(UTF8.java:36)
        at sun.reflect.ClassFileAssembler.emitConstantPoolUTF8(ClassFileAssembler.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:331)
        at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.generateConstructor(ReflectionFactory.java:398)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:360)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1588)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:519)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:681)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1941)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1807)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1770)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1595)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.RemoteRpcInvocation$MethodInvocation.readObject(RemoteRpcInvocation.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2234)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2125)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:464)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
        at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:576)
```

upd.
flink-conf.yaml

```
state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3a://s3-bucket-with-checkpoints/flink-checkpoints
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
state.backend: filesystem
taskmanager.heap.size: 3057m
state.checkpoints.dir: s3a://s3-bucket-with-checkpoints/external-checkpoints
```

[Flink Checkpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJbQL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem by changing state backend from filesystem to rocksdb

Answer (score 1):

I think, this might be related to the `SlidingEventTimeWindow`, which as far as I understand from the checkpoint screenshot is a window of size 2 minutes with a 2-second window slide. Flink creates one copy of each element per window to which it belongs. Thus, in your case for sliding window it creates about 60 copies of element and therefore the state size is 60x times bigger then for a tumbling window.

I guess, on checkpoint flink tries to serialize state and there is not enough memory therefore the GC starts and finally you run out of memory.

Comment: judging by the graphs, it looks like when the flink starts making a savepoint, the kinesis client stops reading, and then after the checkpoint the flink gets a "shock" load.
is that how it should be?
what memory parameter do I need to adjust to have enough memory? on the graphs, I do not see the memory running out. and this happens by accident under the same loads.

Comment: Sources that also implement the CheckpointedFunction interface must ensure that state checkpointing, updating of internal state and emission of elements are not done concurrently. This is achieved by using the checkpointing lock object to protect update of state and emission of elements in a synchronized block. So, new records got collected only within the synchronized block so when the snaphost starts, consumer waits for snapshot to complete. From memory perspective, what is the amount of flink managed memory on each TM ? Could you please provide your `flink-conf.yaml` settings? Thank you.

Comment: attached `flink-conf.yaml` in top post

Comment: I'm sorry for too many questions, but could you also please clarify whether you start the flink cluster in standalone mode or in any containerized environment ? also, what version of flink do you use ? memory management has changed since 1.10. In general, in case of filesystem state backend, it's recommended to set managed memory to zero. This will ensure that the maximum amount of memory is allocated for user code on the JVM.

Comment: flink 1.9 running on AWS EMR (Yarn).
how to disable managed memory? maybe i need to change state backend from filesystem to another one?

Comment: If you are running the 1.9 app in yarn, then the `taskmanager.heap.size: 3057m` setting means that you are acquiring the container with 3057mb ram, but this amount includes the default 25% container cut-off, network memory and only a fraction (0.7 if I'm not mistaken) of on-heap memory is used. You can make it off-heap by setting `taskmanager.memory.off-heap` to `true`. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/mem_setup.html#managed-memory.

Comment: solved problem by changing  state backend from filesystem to rocksdb